# DirectoryNotFoundException when accessing to a custom asp.net application configration file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, iis, application-pool, asp.net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that sometimes is throwing below message error in the windows event log under Application category (Sensitive data has been replaced by other strings):

**Event ID: 1309 - Source: ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0**

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: Excepción no controlada. 
Event time: 10/11/2020 11:28:40 
Event time (UTC): 10/11/2020 10:28:40 
Event ID: dd36b383da324e25b95f955f7d784971 
Event sequence: 627 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-6-132494775147792163 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyAspMvcApp\ 
    Machine name: MyServer 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 4316 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: MyDomain\MyCustomIdentity 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: DirectoryNotFoundException 
    Exception message: No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyAspMvcApp\bin\AppConfig.config'.
   en MyCompany.ApplicationData.Utils.ReadOrdersFolder() en d:\Projects\IntranetModule\Orders\Areas\Order\Controllers\OrderController.cs:línea 37
   en MyCompany.Controls.MyController.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://my.aspnetmvcapp.com/Order/Order/ViewOrderAjax 
    Request path: /Order/Order/ViewOrderAjax
    User host address: 172.XX.X.XX 
    User: MyDomain\oneDomainUser
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: MyDomain\MyCustomIdentity
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 144 
    Thread account name: MyDomain\MyCustomIdentity 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    en MyCompany.ApplicationData.Utils.ReadOrdersFolder() en d:\Projects\IntranetModule\Orders\Areas\Order\Controllers\OrderController.cs:línea 37
   en MyCompany.Controls.MyController.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
   en System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   en System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
 
 
Custom event details:
```

At this point what I am trying to do is to access to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyAspMvcApp\bin\AppConfig.config" file in order to read a tag, in concret, the folder  path where orders will be placed.

AppConfig.config is a simple XML file. Furthermore the path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyAspMvcApp\bin" and configuration file AppConfig.config always exist.

This error does not occurs always, only some times.

I have given full permisions on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyAspMvcApp\ to my application pool identity MyDomain\MyCustomIdentity and also I have given read and execute, show folder contents and read permissions to IIS_IUSRS. Note: IUSR user has not been granted to access this folder.

Any ideas why is happening this?

Comment: I think it caused by the name of configuration file. IIS only can read web.config and web.config will load before application itself. Please change AppConfig.config to web.config and run the application again.

Comment: Another situation, how do you set custom configuration and use it? The correct format is <system.web>
    ...
    <profile configSource =“...” />
    ...
  </system.web>

Comment: @BruceZhang The web.config file already exists and it is in the path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyAspMvcApp
The  AppConfig.config file is a custom extra configuration file that contains custom tags such as path where files are being placed once generated, sql server hosts and database catalogs, etc. The format for web.config file is maintained untouched. Custom elements enclosed by '<' and '>' are only created in the custom configuration file AppConfig.config file. Also AppConfig.config file contains a custom structure but in fact is a typical xml file with objects enclosed by '<' and '>' elements.

Comment: What I mean is <system.web> ... <profile configSource =“...” /> ... </system.web> should be configuated in web.config, not AppConfig.config. To let application know that there is another config file should be read.